# Send commands from Windows to Linux via Batch Script SSH

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, batch

I want to have a simple way of running commands on a remote Linux machine from local Windows machines. To do this I will use batch scripts that send commands over SSH. I have having trouble with both

1. giving `ssh` the bash commands directly and
2. alternatively pointing `ssh` at a `.sh` shell script to send over.

**Solution 1:**

`ssh -T pi@192.168.1.4 'echo hello, world'` gives `bash: echo hello, world: command not found`

The command seems to parse as one token instead of seeing `echo` as the command and the rest as the argument.

**Solution 2:**

```
:: script.bat
@echo off
ssh -T pi@192.168.1.4 < script.sh
pause
```

.

```
# script.sh
echo pt1
echo pt2
if [ -n "str" ]; then
    echo pt3
fi
echo pt4
```

This attempt appears to SSH, complete the first 2 commands, and then hang on the `if` statement indefinitely. It never moves past the `if` conditional if it even makes it that far.

**Summary of Solutions:**

Kamil has a very in-depth explanation, including how `echo` works. It is very helpful to read.

I was already suspicious of the `CRLF`s. After the feedback, for the remainder of the debugging I used `;`-delimited one-liners.

@xenoid has inadvertently pointed out and @Kamil has noticed that my [quoting](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) in **1** is incorrect. I was using single quotes, but that is strict quoting where everything except for `'` is a literal. Not using quotes or using double quotes provides the expected behavior.

I still can't get **2** to work. @Kamil has an excellent solution to just put the shell script on the Linux machine. I will be using this.

Comment: Both `ssh <host> "echo Hello, world"` and `ssh <host> echo "Hello, world"` work for me, from Linux to Linux. Your script.sh method also works, if the script uses Unix lineneds, with CRLF it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer. I cannot explain the behavior of the script but I can explain this:

> `ssh -T pi@192.168.1.4 'echo hello, world'` gives `bash: echo hello, world: command not found`
>
> The command seems to parse as one token instead of seeing `echo` as the command and the rest as the argument.

The explanation is in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24181667/10765659). It reads:

> Single quotes are not used at all by the `cmd.exe` command processor except to enclose the command to run within a `FOR /F` statement

This means your `ssh` got the following arguments: `-T`, `pi@192.168.1.4`, `'echo hello,`, `world'`. Single-quotes got to the tool literally.

An argument to `ssh`, that is not recognized as an option, option-argument or `[user@]hostname`, is considered to be a command or a part of it. Following arguments (if any) are also considered parts of the command. If there are two or more parts then `ssh` will build a command for a remote shell by concatenating them, injecting single spaces in between.

In your case the two parts (`'echo hello,`, `world'`) gave this code to run in a remote shell:

```
'echo hello, world'
```

Solution for uncomplicated commands: use double-quotes, they will be interpreted by `cmd.exe`. This code:

```
ssh -T pi@192.168.1.4 "echo hello, world"
```

will pass the following arguments to `ssh`: `-T`, `pi@192.168.1.4`, `echo hello, world`. This is what you intended in the first place. The remote shell will get:

```
echo hello, world
```

Note when you said "seeing `echo` as the command and the rest as the argument", it's not exactly what happens. The rest is argument**s**, plural. On the remote side `echo` will get *two* arguments: `hello,` and `world`. It will print them as `hello, world` because injecting a single space is what the tool does in such circumstances. If you need multiple spaces between the two then this is what you should do:

```
ssh -T pi@192.168.1.4 "echo 'hello,         world'"
```

Here the double-quotes make `cmd.exe` not split the string, so `ssh` gets it with these spaces. Then on the remote side the single-quotes makes the remote shell not split the (shorter) string, so `echo` gets it with these spaces. Omitting any pair of quotes will result in `hello, world`. Which mechanism is responsible for replacing multiple spaces with just one depends on which quotes you omit.

More complicated commands often need to be modified (especially if they include double-quotes) to prevent the local interpreter from interfering. The linked answer states:

> Here are some important notes about using double quotes `"` with `cmd.exe`.
>
> - Double quotes are a simple state machine. The first `"` turns quoting on, the next turns it off.
> - All special characters are treated as literal values when quoted, except for the `%` and `<newLine>` characters always, and the `!` character if delayed expansion is enabled, and the `^` character if delayed expansion is enabled and `!` also appears somewhere within the line.
> - If quoting is off, then you can escape a `"` as `^"` to prevent it from turning quoting on. But once quoting is on, you cannot escape the closing `"`. The very next `"` will always turn quoting off.

This inconvenience also happens in (local) Bash or any other shell in Linux or wherever. The quoting rules are different but still you need to understand which parts of syntax will be interpreted on the local side, which on the remote side. In Bash you can use single-quotes or here documents, this often helps.

---

A firm way to prevent the local interpreter from altering code intended for the remote interpreter is to make the code not appear as code on the local side. This is what you were trying to do by reading code from a file. I don't know Windows or `cmd.exe` well enough to tell why the approach didn't work; all I know is it works from Linux to Linux, so most likely the culprit is not *solely* in your remote Linux.

Since you have the code in a file, an alternative approach is to copy the file itself to the remote side. Then you can invoke a command like this in your local `cmd.exe`:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.4 ./script.sh
```

This needs the script to be executable on the remote side. Also a proper shebang in the script is advised. You can circumvent these limitations by:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.4 "/bin/sh ./script.sh"
```

(or `/bin/bash` or whatever the script is designed for). Note the double-quotes here are not strictly necessary. I just tend to quote whole multi-word commands invoked with `ssh`.

Copying a script may be done via `scp`, FTP, Samba or some other method. There are quirks though:

1. Shells in Linux/Unix expect scripts to use Unix line endings: LF. In Windows text files use CR+LF. Most protocols copy files as they are, without conversion. FTP being an exception (useful if you know how it works, error-prone if you don't; compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1098338/432690)). Possible approaches:

   - In Windows use a text editor that allows you to save files with Unix line endings. Copy files to Linux without conversion.
   - In Windows use Windows line endings. Copy files to Linux via FTP in text mode.
   - Create in whatever way, copy in whatever way. Finally in Linux [use `dos2unix`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391226/108618). If by any means the file is already in Unix format then `dos2unix` will only replace the file with it exact copy; it will be almost like a no-op. There are [few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368641/108618) [downsides](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249034/108618) in general but in your case they shouldn't matter. So you can use `dos2unix` without a second thought.
2. Shells in Linux/Unix expect scripts [not to have BOM](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#On_UTF-8_and_Byte-Order_Marks_.28BOM.29). Modern `dos2unix` [should fix this](https://superuser.com/a/1478982/432690).
3. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_195) requires a trailing newline character in every line including the last one. If the last line of your script (text file in general) is not terminated by LF, some tools may ignore it as if the line didn't exist. Common shells in Linux seem to accept incomplete lines but other tools may not.