# need POSIX solution to remove special invisible characters from file

Tags: linux, filesystems, sed, special-characters, posix

I have a file that comes to us from a third party (Windows) and is not in our control.

I observed that it has special characters like below:

```
root@DKERP:~# cat -ev ~/check_disk_space.sh
M-oM-;M-?#!/bin/bash^M$
^M$
# Arguments: <mount_points> <min_free_space>^M$
^M$
```

I tried the below solution and it removes all special characters but `M-oM-;M-?`

```
sed -i -e 's/\r//g; s/'$'\302''//g; s/'$'\273''//g' ~/check_disk_space.sh
```

Can you please suggest how can I remove all special characters?

Comment: "M-oM-;M-?" is bytes EF BB BF which are UTF8 for U+FEFF aka Byte Order Mark, which some Windows software adds to the beginning of a file (only), so you can remove it with `1s/^.//` in a UTF8 locale or `1s/^...//` in a singlebyte locale. BTW _GNU_ sed (likely on Linux but not certain) supports `\xhex` and `\ooctal` (but not C-like `\octal`) directly so you don't need to bounce back to shell `$'\octal'`, just like you already didn't for `\r`. **Or just use `dos2unix`;** it removes BOTH CR (`\r`) and BOM, conveniently. Compare https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/ .

Comment: are you suggesting ` sed -i -e '1s/^.//g' ~/check_disk_space.sh`  or `sed -i -e '1s/^...//g' ~/check_disk_space.sh` because it does not work .

Comment: i cant use `dos2unix` as the server and installation is not in scope

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i also tried a few suggestions from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Skip to the section named "Universal solution with `sed`".

---

#### Explanation

`M-oM-;M-?` is how `cat -ev` shows you the [BOM for UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

It looks like the file in question is supposed to be a shell script. Scripts in Linux should be in UTF-8, without BOM, with lines terminated by `\n` (`LF`, `$` in the output of `cat -ev`), not by `\r\n` (`CRLF`, `^M$` in the output of `cat -ev`). You definitely should remove these `\r` characters and the BOM.

`dos2unix` is a tool that converts the newlines, [it can also remove the BOM](https://superuser.com/a/1478982/432690). It's not a portable tool though, you may or may not have it in your Linux.

The troublesome BOM is (hex) `EF BB BF`, in octal it's `357 273 277`.

Your solution with `sed` tries to remove `273`; if it worked, it should have removed `M-;`. If it worked, it would be trivial to add `357` and `277` to it. But the command you used is not POSIX-compliant for at least two reasons:

- The syntax like `$'\273'` in the command is designed to be expanded by the shell and `sed` should get a verbatim byte. Bash supports the syntax, but the purely POSIX shell does not.
- POSIX does not specify `-i` for `sed`. [Even implementations that do support `-i` differ in details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/108618).

---

#### Simple (but not perfect) solution with `tr`

A POSIX tool that removes bytes (well, in theory characters, but [not always in practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228558/108618)) is [`tr -d`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html#tag_20_132). It supports octal representation, so you don't need your shell to expand `$'\273'` and such. The command will be like:

```
<source_file tr -d '\r\357\273\277' >destination_file
```

Warning: [do not redirect output to the `source_file`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558773/108618).

It's not clear to me why you wanted to delete bytes with octal representation `302`. Add `\302` to the above command if you think you need this.

Unfortunately at least some of the bytes we want to remove may appear after the BOM. E.g `»` character is (octal) `302 273` in UTF-8. (Maybe your `sed` is designed to remove this exact character?)

---

#### Alternative simple (and still somewhat flawed) solution with `dd`

To avoid removing matching bytes that are not the BOM, consider a different approach. You can skip the first three bytes, no matter what they are:

```
<source_file dd bs=1 skip=3 >destination_file
```

You want to remove `\r` as well, so the full command will be:

```
<source_file dd bs=1 skip=3 | tr -d '\r' >destination_file
```

Our original `tr` should do fine even without BOM, but if there are fancy characters (like `»`) in the file then the tool may do harm by removing too much. On the other hand our `dd` just removes the first three bytes, so it will not touch bytes later in the file, but it will do harm in cases where there is no three-byte BOM.

If you are sure there is BOM for UTF-8, the solution with `dd` is fine.

---

#### Universal solution with `sed`

A universal solution is the following:

```
<source_file sed "
1 s|^$(printf '\357\273\277')||;
  s|$(printf '\r')||g;
" >destination_file
```

It removes the *exact* BOM from the beginning of the first line only, if the BOM is there; and it does not touch characters like `»` that may appear later. It also removes all carriage return characters. Note in UTF-8 the byte we denote `\r` cannot appear as a part of a multi-byte character, so there is no problem with it similar to the problem with `\273`.

If your `sed` supports `-i` then use it (`sed -i… "…" source_file`) and you're done. The answer continues because you requested a POSIX solution, i.e. without `sed -i`.

---

#### Doing the job of `sed -i`

After using `tr` or `dd`+`tr` or `sed`, you can

```
mv destination_file source_file
```

`sed -i` would do this (or something similar) under the hood. Note your `destination_file` (and thus the new `source_file` after `mv`) has ownership and mode (permissions) not related to the old `source_file`, you may need to correct them. To avoid the problem, try to use `cat` instead of `mv`:

```
<destination_file cat >source_file && rm destination_file
```

Writing back with `cat` is not atomic (in the sense [`mv` inside a single filesystem is most likely atomic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322074/108618)), but it will change neither the ownership nor the mode of your `source_file`. Of course you need write access to the `source_file` for this; so if the ownership and the mode is unfortunate for you (you cannot write to the file) then `cat` won't work, `mv` might. One way or another, eventually you may (or may not) need `chmod` and/or `chown`.

Note that our `mv` or the redirection in our `cat >…` destroys the source data. You should run one xor the other only after you are sure the `destination_file` is correct. Chaining commands with `&&` may help. Example:

```
<source_file sed "
1 s|^$(printf '\357\273\277')||;
  s|$(printf '\r')||g;
" >destination_file \
&& <destination_file cat >source_file \
&& rm destination_file
```